# Terraform variables: How can I restructure my terraform variables data-structure for vnets/subnets/nsgs in a more flatter way?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The following variables.vnet data structure I am using is causing too much complications in terms of being about to use count/for_each and creating subnets/vnets on dynamically. I want a simpler solution to this. I still want to be able to group the related subnets within the respective vnets, but maybe get rid of the excessive lists of maps?

Can someone help me formulate a better way of structuring this?

```js
variable "vnets" {
  default = [
    {
      vnet_name     = "first-vnet"
      address_space = "10.250.0.0"
      network_size  = 16
      subnets = [
        {
          name                     = "test1-subnet"
          bitmask                  = 24
          netnum                   = 1
          service_endponts_enabled = false
          network_security_group   = "test1-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "test1-sg"
              priority                   = 100
              direction                  = "inbound"
              access                     = "allow"
              protocol                   = "tcp"
              source_port_range          = "*"
              destination_port_range     = "*"
              source_address_prefix      = "*"
              destination_address_prefix = "172.16.2.0/24"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          name                     = "test2-subnet"
          bitmask                  = 24
          netnum                   = 2
          service_endponts_enabled = false
          network_security_group   = "test2-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "test2-sg"
              priority                   = 100
              direction                  = "inbound"
              access                     = "allow"
              protocol                   = "tcp"
              source_port_range          = "*"
              destination_port_range     = "*"
              source_address_prefix      = "172.16.0.0/24"
              destination_address_prefix = "172.16.4.0/24"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          name                     = "test3-subnet"
          bitmask                  = 24
          netnum                   = 3
          service_endponts_enabled = true
          network_security_group   = "test3-nsg"
          security_group_rules = [
            {
              name                       = "test3-sg"
              priority                   = 100
              direction                  = "inbound"
              access                     = "allow"
              protocol                   = "tcp"
              source_port_range          = "*"
              destination_port_range     = "*"
              source_address_prefix      = "172.16.2.0/24"
              destination_address_prefix = "172.16.8.0/22"
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      vnet_name     = "second-vnet"
      address_space = "10.251.0.0"
      network_size  = 16
      subnets       = []
    },
    {
      vnet_name     = "third-vnet"
      address_space = "10.252.0.0"
      network_size  = 16
      subnets       = []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: sorry, yes for now. Was hoping for more input, but yours does help! marked as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables.vnet data structure is good, except for the NSG rules, it's unnecessary to put the rules inside the subnet property. You know, a subnet can only be attached with one NSG. So you just need to set which NSG will attach to the subnet. And you could use another variable just for the NSG and the rules separately.

For example, for the subnets, it could like hits:

```
...
subnets = [
        {
          name                     = "test1-subnet"
          bitmask                  = 24
          netnum                   = 1
          service_endponts_enabled = false
          network_security_group   = "test1-nsg"
        },
        ...
      ]
```